# Spring Oauth for Web Application

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a query I am struggling to come to a decent answer with and hoping by vocalizing it someone might be able to guide me or advise me in the right direction.

All our current web applications are build using Spring, which includes the security which is handled by Spring Security module of course.
We are exploring the opportunities of integrating some of our new android projects into these web applications.

After some research and guidance, all flags point towards OAuth2 implementation in Android App and using that to obtain access to relevant parts of the web application server via Restfull calls.

What I am trying to understand now is can we and should we replace our existing Spring Security implementation in our web application and replace it with Spring Oauth2 equivalent.

The overall goal would to be able to have a single security solution that we would use for both website login, app login, and any API implementations that would be exposed to other web applications.

If anyone can also provide a link to a Spring Oauth2 Java Config (not-XML) setup where a user logs in and accesses a page based on their role in a unrestful manner, would also be extremely helpful. Most examples we have found were either extremely complex, focused solely on restfull calls, or only XML configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you did not hear about spring-cloud-security project which extremely simplifies working with oauth2 providers. Take a look at:

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/

There are samples available on github ( right side of above page ). It shows how to set up in case you want to use just one oauth2 provider - check project which shows how to do that for github https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso . You do most of this stuff through configuration in `application.yml` file + add `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation so all machinery starts.

For 'normal' interaction with your web app its pretty straighforward. If you need your app to work as an api for others then you have to maintain tokens, add them to request etc. If client of your api is also your code which you can change then you may use `OAuth2RestTemplate` class which take care about tokens, so you do queries to your api as it was usual/not secured endpoint.

If you need to use for example two different providers for different paths then its more complicated, you have to configure them all like:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate facebookOAuth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(facebookOAuth2ResourceDetails(), clientContext);
}

@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails facebookOAuth2ResourceDetails() {
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resource = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUri);
    resource.setId("id");
    resource.setUserAuthorizationUri(authorizationUri);
    resource.setUseCurrentUri(false);
    resource.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(redirectUri);
    resource.setClientId(clientId);
    resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    resource.setTokenName("tokenname");
    resource.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
    resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);

    return resource;
}
```

and decide which instance of `OAuth2RestTemplate` to use in which case.

//update

If you want to exchange spring security core with authorizing users by some oauth2 provider you can extends `OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends OAuth2SsoConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void match(RequestMatchers matchers) {
  matchers.antMatchers("/admin");
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```

So /admin will be now protected, and user redirected to any authorization server you specify. It requires oauth configuration in `application.yml`.

```
 spring:
    oauth2:
    client: # Sauron
      clientId: app_clientid
      clientSecret: app_secret
      accessTokenUri: http://authorizationserver/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://authorizationserver/oauth/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: header
    resource:
      tokenInfoUri: http://authorizationserver/oauth/check_token
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

Thats why I wrote before that its easy to use just one auhorization server, but in case you need more then its more complicated.

Comment: Thanks @freakman, i actually saw this bit ago but doesn't help answer my query unfortunately. Can Oauth2 be used to replace standard spring security without using restfull calls i.e. normal calls made by browser under non-restfull method. Or should it be implemented as a separate entity just for api calls (note we won't use 3rd party authorisers. we want to create our own server to which its connected)

Comment: it can be used to protect your controllers as 'normal' spring security - this example shows this: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso . More in an update.